# How to list all tables in ABAP programmatically?

Tags: abap

All tables may be listed with t-code SE16 and table DD02L. But how can that list be accessed programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

It is rarely a good idea to access the database tables directly since you will have to deal with all kinds of technicalities you probably don't even know about - active / inactive versions, for example. You will also bypass all security and authorization checks, which might be irrelevant to you personally, but is undesirable in general. To get a list of tables, you can use the function module `RPY_TABLE_SELECT`. This function module will take care of the version handling and provide the description in the language of your choice as well.

Answer (score 1):

Improved [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200212/alex) code in some way and put it as an option:

```
SELECT tabname
 FROM DD02L 
 INTO TABLE @DATA(itab)
WHERE TABCLASS = 'TRANSP'.

LOOP AT itab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<FS>).
 WRITE:/ <FS>.
ENDLOOP.
```

Several things were refined: incline declarations were utilized, field-symbols added, `SELECT *` and `WHERE IN` were omitted and so on. 
Also tables in SAP have only TRANSP class, INTTAB class belongs to structures.

**Note:** the sample is functional since ABAP 7.40, SP08.

Answer (score 0):

An ongoing search resulted in the following snippet:

```
DATA ITAB TYPE TABLE OF DD02L.

SELECT * FROM DD02L INTO TABLE ITAB WHERE TABCLASS IN ('TRANSP', 'INTTAB').

WRITE :SY-SUBRC .

DATA FS TYPE DD02L.

LOOP AT ITAB INTO FS.

  WRITE:/ FS-TABNAME.

ENDLOOP.
```

Table description is given in table DD02T.

Comment: That is an example of very bad coding style and should not be distributed again.

Comment: I assume vwegert is exaggerating here) Your code is not total bummer and makes some sense. However, it can be improved in some ways: for example utilizing incline declarations, field-symbols, omitting `SELECT *` and `WHERE IN` places and so on. Also tables have only `TRANSP` class, and not `INTTAB`.

Comment: @gkubed, added improvements as a separate answer.